# (I redesigned the entire magazine as well but that’s another story)

Tags: punctuation, parentheses

Finally, can someone settle the argument about the period going inside or outside of the close paren in this free-standing sentence?

Comment: What argument are you referencing.

Comment: Without knowing what it’s parenthetical to, it’s impossible to say.

Comment: Is that a complete sentence? (Please provide the context.)